# Magento sort by sold products in last 30 days

Tags: magento, sorting

How can I sort products (in categories) by ordered quantity in last 30 days.

I found [this tutorial](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-products/sort-show-products-by-sold-quantity-in-magento/) but it's not what I really want.

Comment: You can add date filter into the above examples collection right?  $collection->addAttributeToFilter('date_field', array(
       'from' => '2000-09-10',
        ));

Comment: Palanikumar, that would be incorrect; what jorjdaniel needs to do is to add a new sort option to the magento toolbar. The challenge here is that he needs to do a join of the last 30 day orders with the loaded product collection.

Comment: Anyway the tutorial didn't work. When I select to order by ordered_qty it returns `There are no products matching the selection.` even if there's two items in that category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to create a script that calculates these data.

The sales_flat_order_item table contains the information you needs I think (all items ordered with quantity and date among others). Put the result of this calculation (ordered_quantity integer) into a custom new attribute on the product ('popularity'). The script can be run via a cron job to prevent the customer from suffering from it.

Then all you need to do is make this attribute used for sorting and set it as available sorting for the category as well as as default sorting for products (in Magento configuration).